# Analytical Methods for Estimating Probability of Fixation

Tags: evolution, mathematical-models, population-dynamics, population-biology, population-genetics

The probability of fixation $P$ of an allele is an very important measure and there exists several solutions to estimate this probability. Each method has its own assumptions and it is often hard to remember the methods that exists and what are their assumptions.

For example some use $P=2s$, this obviously cannot be right for be values of s, neither for deleterious mutations, and therefore, this approximation seems to make sens only for big population size. Haldane developed a method to calculate the probability of fixation based on the assumption that the fecundity follows a binomial distribution. Kimura used diffusion equation to approximate the probability to fixation. There might exist other solutions. I don't think I ever seen an equation that allows for varying dominance effect $h$.

Can you make a summary of the methods you know for calculating the probability of fixation? Don't forget to highlight the assumptions. A comparison between the accuracy of the different methods would be great as well.